# How to make the jButton action work not in just one run?

Tags: java, swing, variables, jbutton

My code below is a working code and I'd like to apologize for my not so short code. I have a problem with my buttons as they execute their action only once. My problem is that when I click the next button I have a `validateText()` method to check whether the `textarea` is empty or not. Here comes my problem.. when the panel goes back to the empty `textarea` the buttons on the left side will not work anymore. But when you close the program and run it again the button will work unless you click the next button with the empty `textarea`. Is there anyone who can point out my mistake?

```
package cardlayoutalignment;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class gridbaglayoutdemo {
        JFrame Card = new JFrame();

        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,2,2);
        Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray);
        Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);

        public static GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        final static boolean shouldFill = true;

        JPanel container;
        JPanel divider = new JPanel();
        JPanel bodypanel = new JPanel();
        final JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

        JTextArea text_2;
        JTextArea text_3;


        String change = "Finish";
        final JButton btnNext;
        final JButton btnBack;
        int currentCard = 0;
        int cardflag = 0;

        AbstractAction backAction;
        AbstractAction nextAction;

    public gridbaglayoutdemo(){

                Card.setVisible(true);
                Card.setSize(605,333);
                Card.setTitle("Tank Delivery");
                Card.setResizable(false);

                final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
                int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/2);
                int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

            Card.setLocation(x, y);
            Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


            bodypanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            divider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            container = new JPanel(cl);
            container.setLayout(cl);
            cl.show(container, "1");

            panel_1.setLayout(grid);

            JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Enter 1:");
            label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_1.add(label_1, c);

            JComboBox box_1 = new JComboBox();
            box_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 1;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_1.add(box_1,c);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 1;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 2;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
            panel_1.add(label, c);


            panel_2.setLayout(grid);

            JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Enter 2:");
            label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_2.add(label_2,c);

            text_2 = new JTextArea();
            text_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 20;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_2.add(text_2,c);

            JLabel label_22 = new JLabel("");
            label_22.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 1;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 30;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
            panel_2.add(label_22, c);


            panel_3.setLayout(grid);

            JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Enter 3:");
            label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_3.add(label_3,c);

            text_3 = new JTextArea();
            text_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 0;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 20;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
            panel_3.add(text_3,c);

            JLabel label_33 = new JLabel("");
            label_33.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                c.weightx = 0.5;
                c.weighty = 1;
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 30;
                c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
            panel_3.add(label_33, c);

            buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
            buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));

        backAction = new AbstractAction("< Back") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentCard--;
                gridbaglayoutdemo.this.evaluateActions();
            }
        };
        nextAction = new AbstractAction("Next >") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentCard++;
                gridbaglayoutdemo.this.evaluateActions();
            }
        };

            buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
            buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));

                btnBack = new JButton("< Back");
                btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                cl.previous(container);
                                buttonpanel.repaint();
                                cardflag--;
                                if (cardflag==0)
                                {btnBack.setEnabled(false);}
                                if(cardflag<3)
                                {btnNext.setText("Next >");}
                        }   
                });
                btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                btnBack.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                btnBack.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                btnBack.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
            buttonpanel.add(btnBack);

                btnNext = new JButton("Next >");
                btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                cl.next(container);
                                buttonpanel.repaint();

                                cardflag++;
                                if(cardflag<3)
                                {btnBack.setEnabled(true);}
                                if(cardflag==2)
                                {btnNext.setText(change);}
                                if (cardflag==3)
                                {cl.show(container, "3");
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DONE");
                                Window dialog = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnNext );
                                dialog.dispose(); 
                                cardflag=0;
                                btnNext.setText("Next >");
                                }

                                validateText();


                        }   
                });
                btnNext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                btnNext.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                btnNext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                btnNext.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                btnNext.setVisible(true);
            buttonpanel.add(btnNext);

                final JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                Window dialog = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnCancel );
                                dialog.dispose(); 
                        }   
                });
                btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                btnCancel.setFocusable(false);
                btnCancel.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
                btnCancel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                btnCancel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                btnCancel.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
            buttonpanel.add(btnCancel);

            JPanel numberpanel = new JPanel();
            numberpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(221,0));
            numberpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,0,0,10));
            numberpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray));
            numberpanel.setLayout(flow);

                JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
                button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        buttonaction(e);
                        }   
                });
                button_7.setActionCommand("7");
                button_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button_7.setFocusable(false);
                button_7.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                button_7.setFocusPainted(false);
                button_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                button_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                button_7.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
            numberpanel.add(button_7);

            JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
                button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        buttonaction(e);
                        }   
                });
                button_8.setActionCommand("8");
                button_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button_8.setFocusable(false);
                button_8.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                button_8.setFocusPainted(false);
                button_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                button_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                button_8.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
            numberpanel.add(button_8);

            JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
                button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        buttonaction(e);
                        }   
                });
                button_9.setActionCommand("9");
                button_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button_9.setFocusable(false);
                button_9.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                button_9.setFocusPainted(false);
                button_9.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                button_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                button_9.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
            numberpanel.add(button_9);



            Card.add(bodypanel);
                bodypanel.add(divider, BorderLayout.WEST);
                        divider.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);     
                                container.add(panel_1, "1");
                                container.add(panel_2, "2");
                                container.add(panel_3, "3");
                                //container.add(panel_4, "4");
                                //container.add(p5.panel_5, "5");
                                //container.add(p6.panel_6, "6");
                        divider.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                bodypanel.add(numberpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

        private void evaluateActions() {
        ((javax.swing.Action) backAction).setEnabled(currentCard > 0);
        ((javax.swing.Action) nextAction).setEnabled(currentCard < container.getComponentCount() - 1);
        }

        private void buttonaction(ActionEvent e){
            try{
            if(cardflag==1)
                {text_2.append("" + e.getActionCommand());}
            if(cardflag==2)
                {text_3.append("" + e.getActionCommand());}

            }catch(Exception IOe){}
        }

        private void validateText(){
            if(cardflag==2)
            {String text = text_2.getText();
                if (text.isEmpty()==true)
                {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text 2 is empty!");
                cl.show(container, "2");
                }
            }
        }


public static void main(String[] args){
    //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        new gridbaglayoutdemo();         
    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: use `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` to show the window in the center instead of `setLocation(x, y);`

Comment: explain your problem statement a bit more. It's not clear.

Comment: @user3218114 Hi. I've been using that setLocation for a month now and I don't get a problem with it. You won't understand my problem unless you try it out yourself.

Comment: *"I've been using that setLocation for a month now and I don't get a problem with it. You won't understand my problem unless you try it out yourself."*  That code does many things which should be changed in order to get it working *reliably* across machines.

Comment: Ohh. I see. I'll keep that in mind. I just got that code from the previous developer and so I just continue using it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are you doing but I just noticed one thing with the state of `cardflag`.

When the text field is empty and next button is clicked `cardflag = 2` and now button is clicked then below action listener is called.

```
private void buttonaction(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        if (cardflag == 1) {
            text_2.append("" + e.getActionCommand());
        }
        if (cardflag == 2) {
            text_3.append("" + e.getActionCommand());
                ^^^
               //This should be text_2
        }

    } catch (Exception IOe) {
    }
}
```

Comment: you know if you run my program you'll know my problem. How can that be text_2 if the `cardflag` is 2? @_@ my `cardflag` starts with 0 so it should be `cardflag = 1`.

Comment: `..catch(Exception ex) {}..` should be `..catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }..`

Comment: As an aside, `IOe` implies an `IOException` to me, but how can that code throw one?

Comment: @user3771102 Have you tried it after changing it to `text_2` as I suggested?

Comment: @user3771102 the issue is with the state of `cardflag`. Please debug your code and try to find out it yourself because I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figure it out now. Thanks to user3218114. Since I'm clicking the next button my `cardflag` is still adding up and because of that I needed to add -1 in my `cardflag` so that the number of my panel will stay the same and that I won't be needing any additional duplication of my code.

```
private void validateText(){
                if(cardflag==2)
                {String text = text_2.getText();
                    if (text.isEmpty()==true)
                    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text 2 is empty!");
                    cl.show(container, "2");
                    cardflag--;
                    }
                }
            }
```